# Accessing SSL based website on iPhone, BlackBerry, Android, WP7

Tags: iphone, android, iis, blackberry, ssl

I am planning to deploy a website on IIS 7.0 with the SSL certificate with the encryption of 128 bit. Now, my concern is if, any user visits my website through any of the smartphones' web browsers, are there any pitfalls or all goes good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All modern phones are running up-to-date web browsers, and can handle encrypted pages just fine

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problem you probably will face on Android is, that Android <= 2.2 have a very small list of Certification Authorities (CA) it trusts.

Check first, if your certificate is issued from a CA, that is considered as trusted by the most smartphone operating systems (like Verisign etc.). If this is not the case, your users will probably face a security warning alert on their browser.